# Chromecast video disconnection issue

Tags: android, chromecast

I implemented the the things in my chromecast app. but video is not disconnected when cast button disconnected in android phone.

Comment: If you really want any help, you need to completely rewrite your question. Yours look like: "I wrote a program and it doesn't work". Provide the code that you have around the relevant area; do you see an exception, if so produce logs; what do you do for "disconnect" logic? Are you calling stopApplication() or not? What does your receiver logic do when a sender is disconnected?

Answer (score 0):

Try using mini controller on bottom of the phone ui for stop-play. Let the message for that control action take affect . then disconnect.

Comment: I am using Cast companion library. when player open after appllication connected to cast the video play on the TV. then i dissconnected cast button so my video which was play on tv is not stop.